# Facebook OAuth getting only email, possible?

Tags: facebook-oauth

I'm busy to enable login stuff via facebook oauth on my website, but the only thing I want to get is the email of the user.

I saw in dev docs the `'scope=email'` but, it seem's mandatory for the user to allow access to anything about him.

is there's a way to ask him to grant access only on his email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The bare minimum that your app will request from the user is his Basic Information, followed by your extended permissions (in your case, his email address).

Answer (score 1):

nope. email is a so called extended permission. so you have to get the basic set of data of the user. (like: name, fbid, gender, locale).